# Layers in select interaction with swipe in openlayers

Tags: javascript, controls, openlayers, swipe, layer

I use a swipe in Openlayers to show a layer on each side, which can be chosen from a menu. That is, it is not fixed whether a layer will be shown on the right or left side of the swipe. I have two select ol.interaction.Select: right and left side. My question is: how to dynamically change the layers for each select? In the code, `layer1` is fixed to `selectPointerMove_left, but it may be that at some point, this layer will be added on side right.

```
var selectPointerMove_left = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: function(e) {
      return (
        ol.events.condition.pointerMove(e) &&
        e.pixel[0] < map.getSize()[0] * swipe_control.get('position')
      );
    },
    multi: false,
    layers: [layer1],
    style: selectedStyle
});

var selectPointerMove_right = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: function(e) {
      return (
        ol.events.condition.pointerMove(e) &&
        e.pixel[0] > map.getSize()[0] * swipe_control.get('position')
      );
    },
    multi: false,
    layers: [layer2],
    style: selectedStyle
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a `swapped` boolean, if you swap the layers set it true and test in the select conditions:

```
var swapped = false;

var selectPointerMove_left = new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition: function (e) {
    return (
      ol.events.condition.pointerMove(e) &&
      (swapped
        ? e.pixel[0] > map.getSize()[0] * swipe_control.get('position')
        : e.pixel[0] < map.getSize()[0] * swipe_control.get('position'))
    );
  },
  multi: false,
  layers: [layer1],
  style: selectedStyle
});

var selectPointerMove_right = new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition: function (e) {
    return (
      ol.events.condition.pointerMove(e) &&
      (swapped
        ? e.pixel[0] < map.getSize()[0] * swipe_control.get('position')
        : e.pixel[0] > map.getSize()[0] * swipe_control.get('position'))
    );
  },
  multi: false,
  layers: [layer2],
  style: selectedStyle
});
```

Or for more complex cases than a simple swap you could replace the layers array with a filter function and a maintain left/right flag for each layer (or even a three way left/right/both flag where `both` would be valid for both interactions):

```
var selectPointerMove_left = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: function(e) {
      return (
        ol.events.condition.pointerMove(e) &&
        e.pixel[0] < map.getSize()[0] * swipe_control.get('position')
      );
    },
    multi: false,
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
      return (
        {layer === layer1 && layer1Left) ||
        {layer === layer2 && layer2Left)
      );
    },
    style: selectedStyle
});

var selectPointerMove_right = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: function(e) {
      return (
        ol.events.condition.pointerMove(e) &&
        e.pixel[0] > map.getSize()[0] * swipe_control.get('position')
      );
    },
    multi: false,
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
      return (
        {layer === layer1 && !layer1Left) ||
        {layer === layer2 && !layer2Left)
      );
    },
    style: selectedStyle
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The example was with two layers: layer1 and layer2, but I have several.

And it may be that at some point I choose to show layer1 on the left side and layer2 on the side right and vice versa. In this case, in `layers:[layer1]` must come the name of all possible layers? What if the layer is on the right side, but also on the left side?

Comment: I think you would need to use a layer filter to handle that.  I have added a possible setup to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. With your explanations and codes I managed to do what I need.